# How to sort dictionary by value from list using Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, data-analysis

I have data of dictionary:

```
dict_source = {
    'K93': [(('QB2MRR-GASY93RD01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 2 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 1, 'K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]), 
            (('QB2MRR-GASY93RD01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 3 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 2, 'K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),], 
    'K0JA': [(('QB2MRR-GASY0JBK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 2 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 1, 'K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [600, 30]), 
            (('QB2MRR-GASY0JBK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 3 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 3, 'K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [300, 15])], 
    'K03S': [(('QB2MRR-GANT3SBK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 3 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 1, 'K03S', 'AMK03S  ', 0.0, 900.0, 600), [600, 30]), 
            (('QB2MRR-GANT3SBK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 3 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 2, 'K03S', 'AMK03S  ', 0.0, 900.0, 600), [300, 15])], 
    'K1AA': [(('QB2MRR-GASY1ABK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 2 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 2, 'K1AA', 'AMK1AA  ', 0.0, 900.0, 600), [200.0, 10]), 
            (('QB2MRR-GASY1ABK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 3 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 1, 'K1AA', 'AMK1AA  ', 0.0, 900.0, 600), [600, 30])]
}
```

and i have a collection of product type sequences in the form of a list

```
my_list_type_product = ["K03S", "K1AA", "K93", "K0JA"]
```

and my question is **how to sort my dictionary based on my_list_type_product?**. The result what i want like this:

```
{
    'K03S': [(('QB2MRR-GANT3SBK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 3 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 1, 'K03S', 'AMK03S  ', 0.0, 900.0, 600), [600, 30]), 
            (('QB2MRR-GANT3SBK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 3 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 2, 'K03S', 'AMK03S  ', 0.0, 900.0, 600), [300, 15])], 
    'K1AA': [(('QB2MRR-GASY1ABK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 2 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 2, 'K1AA', 'AMK1AA  ', 0.0, 900.0, 600), [200.0, 10]), 
            (('QB2MRR-GASY1ABK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 3 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 1, 'K1AA', 'AMK1AA  ', 0.0, 900.0, 600), [600, 30])],
    'K93': [(('QB2MRR-GASY93RD01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 2 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 1, 'K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]), 
            (('QB2MRR-GASY93RD01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 3 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 2, 'K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]),], 
    'K0JA': [(('QB2MRR-GASY0JBK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 2 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 1, 'K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [600, 30]), 
            (('QB2MRR-GASY0JBK01', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W SHIFT 3 Daily', 'ASSYMIRROR 2W LINE 1', 1200, 3, 'K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [300, 15])]
}
```

Comment: Don't sort the dictionary.  It's best to think about dictionaries as unsorted, like SQL tables.  If you want to ACCESS it in that order, do `for key in my_list_type_product:` and then use `dict_source[key]`.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using panda dataframe:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(dict_source).transpose().sort_index().to_dict()
sortedDict = {list(v.keys())[0]: list(v.values())[0] for k,v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the keys and just order them and then pull the original dictionary's property values in, it becomes simpler to handle.

```
ordered_source = { key: dict_source[key] for key in sorted(dict_source.keys()) }
```